# iOS - InputStream: No buffer space available (55)

Tags: ios, swift, streaming, inputstream, outputstream

I know there are a lot of questions about delegate methods not being called, but this is a problem with a delegate method that is initially being called and then stops being called.

So basically I have a stream that is created

```
outputStream = try self.appDelegate.connectionManager.sessions[sessionIndex!].startStream(withName: "newStream", toPeer: peerID!)
```

When the stream is created, I have delegate method that is called which does the following. I have print statements, and it seems that this method runs fine, so I don't believe the issue is here:

```
    func startedStreamWithPeer(_ peerID: MCPeerID, inputStream: InputStream) {
        self.recordingQueue.sync {
            self.inputStream = inputStream
            self.inputStreamIsSet = true
            self.inputStream!.delegate = self
            self.inputStream!.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            self.inputStream!.open()

            self.outputStream!.delegate = self
            self.outputStream!.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
            self.outputStream!.open()

            self.startRecording()
        }
    }
```

Then I write to the output stream

```
let output = self.outputStream!.write(audioBuffer, maxLength: audioBuffer.count)
```

And on another device I receive data from the stream:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {

    switch (eventCode) {

    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("\(#file) > \(#function) > Error has occurred on input stream")

    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("\(#file) > \(#function) > New data has arrived")

        receivingQueue.sync {
            self.readFromStream()
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called twice and is never called again. However, I can see that the stream is still being written on, because eventually this error is continuously printed out:

```
[GCKSession] Failed to send a DTLS packet with 1198 bytes; sendmsg error: No buffer space available (55).
```

Also, when I go to the debug navigator in xCode I can see that data is being sent and received. Approximately 0.2 mbps of data both ways.